# How do I loop through a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through this object and modify some values however I'm getting just the key when I log it.

```
this.restProviderService.getMessages(this.gameService.getStepId(), this.gameService.teamId).subscribe(messages => {
      console.log(messages);
      for (var m in messages) {
        console.log(m);
      }
      
    });
```

console.log(messages)

```
[
    {
        "id": "3",
        "chatId": "1_1",
        "user_id": "21",
        "userName": "batman",
        "msg": "banananananana",
        "createdAt": "1632507755"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "chatId": "1_1",
        "user_id": "31",
        "userName": "jennyg",
        "msg": "asdfasdfasdf",
        "createdAt": "1632507721"
    }
]
```

Console.log(m)

```
0
1
```

Comment: Did you mean `for (var m of messages) `?

Comment: when I use "of" I get Type 'Messages' is not an array type or a string type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for in loop in JS gives you the key. What you do is

```
      for (var m in messages) {
        var message = messages[m];
        console.log(message);
      }
```

or

```
      for (var m of messages) {
        console.log(m);
      }
```

Comment: When I use of I get "Type 'Messages' is not an array type or a string type."

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof messages)` give you? If it's an object the first option should still work.

Comment: yes the first one works. just wondering why the 2nd one doesnt

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `for...of` loop.

In Javascript, a `for...in` loop will return the index each iteration. (0, 1, so on)

A `for...of` loop will return the item at each sequential index.

```
      for (var m of messages) {
        console.log(m);
        //Will log each item in the array in order
      }
```

You could also use the array method `forEach`:

```
messages.forEach((m, index) => {
    console.log(m); // Will print each object
    console.log(index); // 0, 1, 2
});
```

[Relevant MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

You may also be having trouble because you are dealing with an "array-like object", which can be returned from some methods. Here are some [ways](https://dzone.com/articles/js-array-from-an-array-like-object) to convert it to a usual array. But, TLDR:

```
 let typicalArray = [...messages];
//Do stuff with typicalArray
```